# How can I optimize large table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, bigdata

I have a table with nearly 30 M records and size is 6.6 GB. I need to query some data from it and use group by and order by. It takes me too long to query the data, I lost connection to DB so many times...

I have index on all necessary fields as key and composite key. What else can I do to make it faster for the query?

Example query:

```
select id, max(price), avg(order) from table group by id, date order by id, location.
```

Comment: well you should specify only the needed columns and avoid the usage of * in select query

Comment: Do you have a `WHERE` clause anywhere? if you are pulling in 30M+ records, I would expect slow behavior.  In fact, your PHP script may be timing out.

Comment: I don't know if it's an option for you, but it could be a good oportunity to do it in a nosql database like mongodb or couchbase using the map reduce paradigm.

Comment: drop all indexes and try this one (id,date).

Answer (score 0):

use `EXPLAIN query`, where query is your query. For example: `EXPLAIN select * from table group by id, date order by id, location`.

You'll see a table where MySQL analyses your query and shows which indices it looks for. Possibly you don't have sufficient (god enough) indices.

Comment: I tried this before. But in mysql this doesn't give you the correct answer. For example I already have index on id, but when I explain select * from table order by id it still shows null under keys.

Comment: @Suanmeiguo can you paste exact output of the explain statement? This will help a lot to give you any hint

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  With no filter (WHERE clause) and AVG the entire tables has to be read.

The only thing I can think of is to have a new table with ID, AVG_ORDER, MAX_PRICE (or whatever you need) and update that using a trigger or stored procedure when you insert/update new rows.

an index on ID,PRICE index might help you if you didn't need that pesky average.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing isn't going to do you any good.  You're averaging a column, so you have to read every row in the table.  That's going to take time.